# Permission issue while executing downloaded pipeline artifact in Azure devops CI

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using multiple stages in my pipeline to understand the different paradigms.
To share files between stages, I made use of pipeline artifacts. Building in one stage and testing the result in another.
To support this, I have a simple C file, which prints hello.

My pipeline

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo compiling the c file
              gcc hello.c -o hello
              echo finished compiling
              echo "publishing the contents"
          - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            artifact: myobj

  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Testing
        steps:
         - download: current
           artifact: myobj
         - script: |
              cd  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/myobj
              ./hello
```

I get following error message :

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/3ba036fd-22vm0-4e54-b5a4-3ce3ce00f7e6.sh: line 4: ./hello: Permission denied
##[error]Bash exited with code '126'.
```

Is there anything conceptual that I am missing? Or in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restoring the artifact hasn't restored the executable bit on the build outcome.

Add a script step that does:

```
chmod +x ./hello
```

Or add it to your existing script:

```
         - script: |
              cd  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/myobj
              chmod +x ./hello
              ./hello
```

Comment: wow! that worked. So the pipeline artifacts dont restore the executable when downloaded is it?

Comment: That's what I wrote...